# How to manage blank space in Directory name in .gitcongfig commands?

Tags: git

I was trying to set global editor path inside `.gitconfig` configuration file, whereas the new editor was inside a sub folder under the "Program Files" folder. The statement:

```
[core]
    editor = C:/Program Files/xxx/xxx
```

doesn't work because of the space in between 'Program' and 'Files'

When I installed the desired editor in a folder without blank in its name, it functioned well.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux you need to escape out spaces and special character with a backslash like:

```
[core]
    editor = C:/Program\ Files/xxx/xxx
```

Comment: Quite possibly -- but if that works it's because `git` recognizes backslash escapes.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
editor = 'C:/Program Files/xxx/xxx'
```